# Passing Arguments or Passing a List and Referring to its Parts – Which Gives Better Performance?

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, function-construction, memory, code-review

Which is better for optimizing speed, memory, and coding "safety" – passing arguments to a function or passing a list to the function and call the list's parts?

That is, which of the following gives better performance?

```
f[#1, #2, ..., #n] &[x1, x2, ..., xn]
```

or

```
f[#[[1]], #[[2]], ..., #[[n]]] &[{x1, x2, ..., xn}]
```

Both, of course, give the same output...

```
f[x1,x2,...,xn]
```

Assume `f` is complicated enough and `n` is large enough for any performance differences to be significant.

Comment: Well, it seems like neither of these methods would work in practice—the syntax is not correct, per my understanding—but assuming you want to use some similar variation of this, I would point out that in either case, you’ll need to know in advance how many `n` arguments there will be, which may cause some issues in the future that would be avoided by generalizing the method to not require advanced knowledge of what `n` is.

Comment: @CATrevillian Do you mean the …’s? I know that syntax is technically not correct, but I thought context made the meaning obvious.

Comment: `f@@{x1,x2,…,xn}` ?

Comment: Related but different question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/251146/12697

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the following simplistic benchmark, passing a single argument-list `g[{x1,x2,x3,...,xn}]` is about 100×–1000× faster than passing arguments separately `f[x1,x2,x3,...,xn]` when using large numbers of arguments:

```
f[x__] := Total[{x}]     (*  slow: call as f[x1,x2,x3,...,xn]    *)
g[x_]  := Total[x]       (*  fast: call as g[{x1,x2,x3,...,xn}]  *)

SeedRandom[1234];
a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^6];

f @@ a // AbsoluteTiming
(*    {0.17291, 499561.}    *)

g @ a // AbsoluteTiming
(*    {0.000386, 499561.}    *)
```

It appears that calling `g` is limited by the actual calculation of `Total`, whereas calling `f` is limited by the pattern-matching overhead.

Comment: Wouldn’t this analysis be particular to the function ‘Total’?

Comment: I don't think so. `Total` is extremely fast and does not present a bottleneck here. If you don't believe it, you can replace `Total` with some other function and benchmark again.

Comment: Good example. But there may be use cases where the list arg would require dereferencing individual elements. In such cases, if the input is not a packed array it might be faster to not use the list form.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I would assume that the `f`-form dereferences every argument by default, and so would be even slower when applied to a non-packed array, irrespective of any dereferencing happening inside the function call. Or do you have a concrete example in mind where `f` would be faster than `g`?

Comment: In the f form there is no list to dereference. That said, I might try to create an example when I have access to my desktop machine (next week).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau No pressure intended, but I am curious if you found the time to construct an example.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you are asking if

```
Function[{x1, x2}, f[x1, x2]] [x1, x2]
```

is better in some sense than

```
Function[x, f[x[[1]], x[[2]]]]@ {x1, x2}
```

with respect to optimizing speed, memory, and coding
"safety". With regard to speed and memory, it is possible
to test performance with controlled experiments.
With regard to coding "safety", that is a matter of opinion
and taste.
Without some specific details I do not think it is possible
to give an appropriate answer.