# A Function of Arguments or a Function of a List of those Arguments – Which is Recommended?

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, function-construction, memory, code-review

Which is recommended from a programming perspective and has better performance in memory and speed given guaranteed identical output – a function taking many arguments and then referring to those arguments directly or a function taking a single list containing those arguments as elements and then referring to those elements using `Part[]`?

That is, if *n* is large or *f* is called many times, which of the following is better to use given the output is the same?

```
f[x1_,x2_,...,xn_]:=(*body refers to x1,x2,...,xn directly*)
```

or

```
f[list_]:=(*body calls list[[1]],list[[2]],...,list[n]*)
```

For small *n*, standard practice is to use the former, but I am wondering if things change for very large *n*.

Comment: Related but different question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/251113/passing-arguments-or-passing-a-list-and-referring-to-its-parts-which-gives-bet

Comment: I don't think any of them is obviously better than the other. The answer will depend on the context. If performance is your top priority, there are probably better ways to improve it than to make this change. I can imagine situations where the list approach makes it easier to achieve better performance (by avoiding unpacking, or making use of vectorization), but using a list _alone_ won't make anything faster. Instead, it will make it possible for you to write the code in a way that _might_ make things faster in certain situations.

Comment: In particular, if you are going to explicitly access `list[[1]]`, `list[[2]]`, etc. inside of the definition of the function, then using a list likely won't enable any performance improvements. I would not normally choose between these based on performance but based on how convenient they make it to use `f`.

Comment: I think the difference is probably smaller in Mathematica than you might think as you can also use `f[args__]:=Module[{list={args}},]` and then access list members. Other than that I agree with Szabolcs answer, whether on or the other is "better" is not obvious and depends a lot on context: what does the function do and how is it used, who is using it, what is the meaning of the parameters, what are the performance requirements and such things. Without knowing any of that, it will be difficult for anyone to answer your question...